# apache returns empty page instead of php file

Tags: php, apache, apache2

I have a little problem, I have a php file that start like this:

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", true);
echo "test"; 
exit();
```

Somehow this returns an empty page?!

I use `ubuntu 10.10`, `gvim` and `apache2`

Can this have something to do with `utf-8` formatting? I just switched to ubuntu and `gvim` so I am not sure if I use `utf-8` or not, but I know it has been known to cause this problem.

EDIT:

When I change the file to

```
<?php
test
```

Nothing shows up, but if I change it to:

```
test
<?php
```

test shows up ?!

Comment: If you right click on page and view the source what do you see? if you see your php code you need to install php/configure apache to use php for .php files

Comment: soure is blank and all my other pages work (php pages), I have modified the php file today in linux with gvim. That must have caused the problem..

Comment: so one page, valid url, on the server fails, and the rest are all fine?

Comment: Can we assume you have closed the PHP code (?>)?  Try running the code from the command line interface and that might display an error that isn't showing via the browser.

Comment: You may have spurious characters, or utf8 chars that look similar. Try retyping it from scratch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try replacing the start of your script with this:

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", true);
error_reporting( E_ALL );
echo "test";
```

If you still have a blank output, create a new file and copy-paste the content of the faulty file across one line/section/control structure at a time, executing the script after each section is transferred. The section you transfer before you get a blank output is probably your cuprit.

Also, try looking at your Error Logs - they may contain details of the error being experienced and causing the blank output. (In fact, I'd do that first.)

Also, with reference to the code snippets included in your original question:

```
<?php
test
```

Will always fail, as it is not correct syntax.

```
<?php
echo 'test';
```

Should result in "test" being printed to the screen.

Comment: The `E_all` is apparently not set by default in apache2 in ubuntu, but is set by default in `xampp` in windows. Found the error now..

Comment: These lines helped me using IIS as well.

Answer (score 0):

For other people who may have the same problem as me: my PHP script tags were not well-formed!
Bad: `<? php>` instead of good: `<?php>`